# Error in pushing my django app with chargebee integrate on dotcloud

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I am pushing my django app on dotcloud which is integrated with chargebee. I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
15:26:36.355239: [www.0]   File "createdb.py", line 7, in <module>
15:26:36.356211: [www.0]     from wsgi import *
15:26:36.356725: [www.0]   File "/home/dotcloud/rsync-1390404227083/wsgi.py", line 4, in <module>
15:26:36.357324: [www.0]     from hellodjango.wsgi import application
15:26:36.357819: [www.0]   File "/home/dotcloud/rsync-1390404227083/hellodjango/hellodjango/wsgi.py", line 6, in <module>
15:26:36.358456: [www.0]     import django.core.handlers.wsgi
15:26:36.358990: [www.0]   File "/opt/ve/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 11, in <module>
15:26:36.359733: [www.0]     from django.core.handlers import base
15:26:36.360280: [www.0]   File "/opt/ve/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 12, in <module>
15:26:36.360963: [www.0]     from django.db import connections, transaction
15:26:36.361626: [www.0]   File "/opt/ve/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
15:26:36.362305: [www.0]     signals.request_started.connect(reset_queries)
15:26:36.362845: [www.0]   File "/opt/ve/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 88, in connect
15:26:36.363499: [www.0]     if settings.DEBUG:
15:26:36.364079: [www.0]   File "/opt/ve/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
15:26:36.364739: [www.0]     self._setup(name)
15:26:36.365279: [www.0]   File "/opt/ve/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 49, in _setup
15:26:36.365926: [www.0]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
15:26:36.366452: [www.0]   File "/opt/ve/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
15:26:36.367101: [www.0]     % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
15:26:36.367908: [www.0] ImportError: Could not import settings 'hellodjango.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named chargebee
```

Answer (score 0):

Login to your django shell and check the environment variables if it point to your app 
settings.

```
python manage.py shell
```

Run these commands in django console

```
In [1]: import os

In [2]: os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"]
```

You should see an output like:

> <appname>.settings

In your case it should be **hellodjango.settings**

If it is different, set it in your manage.py file.

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "<appname>.settings")
```

This works for me when I install ChargeBee through pip under /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages [not under site_packages]

Check where ChargeBee is installed and see if that path is present in the sys.path. If not doing a `sys.path.append("chargebee_installation_path")` should do.